# CloudML jobs don't terminate when TensorFlow 1.9 is used

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

Our CloudML training jobs don't terminate after training is done when TF 1.9 (which is [officially supported](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/runtime-version-list)) is used. Jobs just sit there indefinitely. Interestingly there are no problems with CloudML jobs running on TF 1.8. Our models are created via `tf.Estimator`.

A typical log (when TF <=1.8 is used) is:

```
I  Job completed successfully.
I  Finished tearing down training program. 
I  ps-replica-0 Clean up finished.  ps-replica-0
I  ps-replica-0 Module completed; cleaning up.  ps-replica-0
I  ps-replica-0 Signal 15 (SIGTERM) was caught. Terminated by service. 
This is normal behavior.  ps-replica-0
I  Tearing down training program. 
I  master-replica-0 Task completed successfully.  master-replica-0
I  master-replica-0 Clean up finished.  master-replica-0
I  master-replica-0 Module completed; cleaning up.  master-replica-0
I  master-replica-0 Loss for final step: 0.054428928.  master-replica-0
I  master-replica-0 SavedModel written to: XXX  master-replica-0
```

When TF 1.9 is used we see the following:

```
I  master-replica-0 Skip the current checkpoint eval due to throttle secs (30 secs). master-replica-0 
I  master-replica-0 Saving checkpoints for 20034 into gs://bg-dataflow/yuri/nine_gag_recommender_train_test/trained_model/model.ckpt. master-replica-0 
I  master-replica-0 global_step/sec: 17.7668 master-replica-0 
I  master-replica-0 SavedModel written to: XXX master-replica-0
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Couple of questions:1)  Are you doing distributed training?
2) What is the order (most recent first or last?) for the logs from TF 1.9? Was "I master-replica-0 SavedModel written to: XXX master-replica-0" the last stackdriver log for TF 1.9?

Comment: Also, it would be helpful if you can send the job id to cloudml-feedback@google.com.

Comment: @GuoqingXu 1) Yes. 2) `Skip the current checkpoint ...` was the last

Comment: @GuoqingXu Job id was sent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upon examining the logs from the job id you sent it looks like only half the workers finished their task and the other half were stuck, hence the master was waiting on them to be alive which caused your job to be stuck.

By default when using tf.Estimator, the master waits for the all the workers to be alive. In large scale distributed training with many workers it's important to set device_filters so that master only relies on PS to be alive and similarly workers should also rely only on PS to be alive.

The solution is to set your device filters in tf.ConfigProto() and pass it to session_config parameter of tf.estimator.RunConfig().
You can find more details here: https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/distributed-training-details#set-device-filters